# Integrate $\int \frac{\cos 2x}{(\sin x+\cos x)^2}\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration

> Integrate $$\int \frac{\cos 2x}{(\sin x+\cos x)^2}\mathrm dx$$

I was integrating my own way.

$$\int \frac{\cos 2x}{\sin^2x+2\sin x\cos x+cos^2}\mathrm dx$$
$$\int \cot 2x \mathrm dx$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln |\sin2x|+c$$

I guess I didn't do any mistake. But, my book had derived something else.

$$\int \frac{\cos 2x \mathrm dx}{1+\sin 2x}$$ By taking $1+\sin 2x=z$ By differentiating the value,
$\cos 2x \mathrm dx=\frac{1}{2}\mathrm dz$
Continue to main equation,
$$\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{z}\mathrm dz$$
$$\frac{1}{2}ln|z|+c=\frac{1}{2}\ln |1+\sin 2x|+c$$

Why both answers are different? I don't think it's possible to derive one to another.

Comment: $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x =1$ not $=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1\neq0$, there's a mistake in the first solution.

Answer (score 0):

notice that:
$$\frac{\cos 2x}{\cos^2x+2\cos x\sin x+\sin^2x}=\frac{\cos 2x}{\color{red}{1}+2\cos x\sin x}=\frac{\cos 2x}{1+\sin2x}$$
this is because:
$$\sin^2x+\cos^2x\equiv1$$
and:
$$\sin2x=2\cos x\sin x$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative:
$$\frac{\cos 2x}{(\cos x+\sin x)^2}=\frac{\cos^2 x-\sin^2x}{(\cos x+\sin x)^2}\\
=\frac{(\cos x+\sin x)(\cos x-\sin x)}{(\cos x+\sin x)^2}=\frac{\cos x-\sin x}{\cos x+\sin x}\\
=\frac{(\cos x+\sin x)'}{(\cos x+\sin x)}$$
now sub $u=\cos x+\sin x$